# How to properly setup cron?

Tags: python, linux, cron

So, I have a python script which appends me a file. I want to schedule it with cron, to be run every minute. I tried a lot of solutions, but still cron is not running my script.

Here is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime

f = open("test.txt", "a+")
f.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

And this is my cron file:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/iczyrskidc/PycharmProjects/testzone/testzone.py
```

I tried to give a permission to a file with:

```
chmod +x testzone.py
```

And this is output of log file:

```
Aug 26 11:39:01 OptiPlex-7010 CRON[12502]: (iczyrskidc) CMD (/home/iczyrskidc/PycharmProjects/testzone/testzone.py)
```

Any ideas what's happening that the cron is not working?

Comment: Where are you looking for your output file?

Comment: I think you need to add `python` before the route of the file

Comment: In the same directory where the python script is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/iczyrskidc/PycharmProjects/testzone && /usr/bin/python3 testzone.py
```

Comment: In the code you shared your question, you may find the output file in the root directory